# __iter__ in Class file, for loop

Tags: python

I currently have my class

```
class People():
    def __init__(self, number ,name, age, height):
        self.number = number
        self.name = name
        self.age= age
        self.height= height
```

and I am trying to write a for loop to get each person and I was told I need to write a **iter** How would I write this so I can do

```
for i in People():
    print(i.Name)
```

and it will print every persons name thats in the class

Output would be  :

```
James
Carson,
Carlson
```

Comment: This is kind of too broad...

Comment: So... Where..do the names come from???????, because you don't have `*args` or three arguments so...???

Comment: It's hard to even know where to start with the code presented. Before you get to this point, you'll need to review and improve your understanding of iterable types in Python and standard usage of classes and instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `People` class apparently stores information of just one person, so if you intend it to be a collection of multiple persons, you should make `Person` and `People` two separate classes, with `People` containing a collection of `Person` instances, so that you can implement an `__iter__` method for the `People` class that returns an iterator to allow iteration over a `People` object to retrieve the `Person` objects contained within:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, number, name, age, height):
        self.number = number
        self.name = name
        self.age= age
        self.height= height

class People:
    def __init__(self):
        self.persons = []
    def add_person(self, person):
        self.persons.append(person)
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.persons)
```

so that:

```
people = People()
people.add_person(Person(123, 'James', 32, 175))
people.add_person(Person(345, 'Carson', 25, 180))
people.add_person(Person(567, 'Carlson', 41, 169))
for i in people:
    print(i.name)
```

would output:

```
James
Carson
Carlson
```